# can a non-facebook connect user see facebook connect images?

Tags: php, facebook

I am incorporating fb connect into a social site I built so I have mixed users (some non-fb and some are). If I only store the fb users profile pics as the img urls, will the images load for non-fb users when they see the fb user's profile as well as still be visible when the user logs off? Or do i literally have to pull the user's fb pic and store them in my img repo that I currently have? I believe it would be easier just to store the img url if possible.

1. Can I access user's facebook profile pics when they are not on my site? (via database storing img url)
2. Can users not logged into facebook see them?
3. If not, is there an alternative method that would allow me to sync their profile pics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this applies to the API or anything, but I was able to view my own Facebook profile picture directly even when logged out.

EDIT

This also works with the Graph API, e.g. [`https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor/picture`](https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor/picture).

Comment: Thanks, that helps somewhat, I'm at the point in the development of this site where i can choose one way or another, but dont want to waste time trying to implement something that wont work, or something overly clunky because I dont want the former to happen. So i was just seeing if someone knew already.

Comment: Edit: tried it with the API. Looks like you'll be fine storing the URLs.